# How to uncomment and comment lines in /etc/fstab by matching the whole line?

Tags: linux, text-processing, sed

I have the below lines in the my /etc/fstab file:

```
#
# /etc/fstab
# Created by anaconda on Sun Aug 23 14:32:22 2020
#
# Accessible filesystems, by reference, are maintained under '/dev/disk'
# See man pages fstab(5), findfs(8), mount(8) and/or blkid(8) for more info
#
/dev/mapper/rootvg-rootlv /                       xfs     defaults        0 0
UUID=af74c8xz-e6ec-2387-b2xe-cdc32519a69f /boot                   xfs     defaults        0 0
UUID=GH4E-B04C          /boot/efi               vfat    defaults,uid=0,gid=0,umask=0077,shortname=winnt 0 0
#/dev/mapper/rootvg-homelv /home                   xfs     defaults        0 0
/dev/mapper/rootvg-optlv /opt                    xfs     defaults        0 0
#/dev/mapper/rootvg-tmplv /tmp                    xfs     defaults        0 0
/dev/mapper/rootvg-usrlv /usr                    xfs     defaults        0 0
/dev/mapper/rootvg-varlv /var                    xfs     defaults        0 0
/dev/mapper/rootvg-homelv /home                   xfs    nodev        1 2
/dev/mapper/rootvg-tmplv /tmp                    xfs    defaults,nodev,nosuid,noexec        1 2
tmpfs /dev/shm tmpfs nodev,nosuid,noexec 0 0
UUID=34g5et-fg55-40er-bx8u-9fhe47f986ab   /datadisk   ext4   defaults,nofail   1   2
/dev/disk/cloud/azure_resource-part1    /mnt    auto    defaults,nofail,x-systemd.requires=cloud-init.service,comment=cloudconfig       0       2
```

There are two entries for `/home` and `/tmp`. I need to uncomment the commented `/home` and `/tmp` and comment out the the other `/home` and `/tmp` lines.

So, my final file should look like this:

```
#
# /etc/fstab
# Created by anaconda on Sun Aug 23 14:32:22 2020
#
# Accessible filesystems, by reference, are maintained under '/dev/disk'
# See man pages fstab(5), findfs(8), mount(8) and/or blkid(8) for more info
#
/dev/mapper/rootvg-rootlv /                       xfs     defaults        0 0
UUID=af74c8xz-e6ec-2387-b2xe-cdc32519a69f /boot                   xfs     defaults        0 0
UUID=GH4E-B04C          /boot/efi               vfat    defaults,uid=0,gid=0,umask=0077,shortname=winnt 0 0
/dev/mapper/rootvg-homelv /home                   xfs     defaults        0 0
/dev/mapper/rootvg-optlv /opt                    xfs     defaults        0 0
/dev/mapper/rootvg-tmplv /tmp                    xfs     defaults        0 0
/dev/mapper/rootvg-usrlv /usr                    xfs     defaults        0 0
/dev/mapper/rootvg-varlv /var                    xfs     defaults        0 0
#/dev/mapper/rootvg-homelv /home                   xfs    nodev        1 2
#/dev/mapper/rootvg-tmplv /tmp                    xfs    defaults,nodev,nosuid,noexec        1 2
tmpfs /dev/shm tmpfs nodev,nosuid,noexec 0 0
UUID=34g5et-fg55-40er-bx8u-9fhe47f986ab   /datadisk   ext4   defaults,nofail   1   2
/dev/disk/cloud/azure_resource-part1    /mnt    auto    defaults,nofail,x-systemd.requires=cloud-init.service,comment=cloudconfig       0       2
```

I tried the below two commands but it is commenting more lines than I need because it's finding more matches especially for the second `sed` command.

```
sed -i '/defaults,nodev,nosuid,noexec/ s/^/#/' /etc/fstab
sed -i '/nodev/ s/^/#/' /etc/fstab
```

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A GNU Sed approach,

```
sed -Ei '/home|tmp/{s/^#//;t;s/^/#/}' file
```

- `/home|tmp/` If line matches `home` or `tmp`,

  - `{s/^#//;t;s/^/#/}` Remove `#` in the line start. If it was not there, substitute the line start by `#`.

An Awk alternative

```
awk '$2 ~ /home|tmp/{ if (!( sub(/^#/, "") )) $1="#"$1} 1' file
```

- `$2 ~ /(home|tmp)/` If 2nd field contains `home` or `tmp`,

  - `if (!( sub(/^#/, "") ))` Try to match a `#` in the line start and delete it. If the operation was not successful (because there was no `#` in the line start),

    - `$1="#"$1` Append a `#` to the line start.
- `1` Print the resulting line.

If you have Gawk, you can add the `-i inplace` flag to edit the file in-place, but I find it better to redirect the output to a file and then overwrite the original file after checking that all went right.

Answer (score -1):

With ansible module lineinfile
especially if you have to do it for multiple hosts : https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/lineinfile_module.html